# Hide list items when searching

Tags: javascript

I have a list of items that I would like to filter, at the moment all of the items are visible but how can I make it so that the results only show when a user types a name?

I tried changing the li to be `block` but did work.

```
 li[i].style.display = "none";
```

I am new to JS and currently doing some courses.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<h2>Car Directory</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Cars" title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Volvo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Mazda</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Toyota</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Yamaha</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Honda</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dodge</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my pen:
https://codepen.io/emmabbb/pen/wvrpqbp

Comment: Please put testable code here instead of linking to it whenever possible.

Comment: It seems the code is working correctly. It is filtering the list items by input text. What is it that you want to achieve that is different from the current behavior?

Comment: I just want to see an empty search box and if someone types in BMW it will show. So reverse of what I have, so hide all items and how as you type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the searchbox isn't empty by adding `filter` to the if statement:

```js
if (filter && txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)
```

and call your function after defining it:
`myFunction()`

**ALSO: for your use case I think using the `input` event would be better than `keyup`

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (filter && txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

myFunction()
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<h2>Car Directory</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Cars" title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Volvo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Mazda</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Toyota</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Yamaha</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Honda</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dodge</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was after! I learned a lot from your changes. Thanks again kind person.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with HTML only, without JavaScript.

```html
<h2>Car Directory</h2>
<input list="cars" placeholder="Search for Cars">

<datalist id="cars">
    <option value="Volvo">
    <option value="BMW">
    <option value="Mazda">
    <option value="Toyota">
    <option value="Yamaha">
    <option value="Honda">
    <option value="Dodge">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Oh also a very good solution! Noted thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can initially hiden the list. As soon as something is entered, you can delete the hide class.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");    
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");    
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  
    if (input.value.length > 0)  {
      ul.classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
      ul.classList.add('hide');
    }
  
   
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; 
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<h2>Car Directory</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Cars" title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL" class="hide">
  <li><a href="#">Volvo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Mazda</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Toyota</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Yamaha</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Honda</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dodge</a></li>
</ul>
```